# How to call custom method in class based views

Tags: python, django

I was using function based views and was getting output correctly.
However when I changed it to **class based views** while invoking function I am getting error **Method Not Allowed (POST):**

views file"

```
class ChatBot(TemplateView):
    # extend from TemplateView
    template_name = 'bot/chatbot.html'
    //**Getting error in calling bot function**

class MessagePassing(View):
    def bot(request):
        response_data={}
        response_data['input'] = request.POST['message']
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),
                        content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: **views.py file is as follows**   class ChatBot(TemplateView):  # extend from TemplateView  
    template_name = 'bot/chatbot.html'  
  
//**Getting error in calling bot function**    

class MessagePassing(View):  
    def bot(request):  
        response_data={}  
        response_data['input']= request.POST['message']  
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")

Comment: Show your code, what you've tried

Comment: Edit the question and add it. Dont add it in comments.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3r9q7nje/

Comment: I have pasted the code in jsfiddle I am not able to post it in question

Comment: add the full code in views please. `ChatBot`

Comment: This is the full code of views.py and urls.py

Answer (score 1):

Use `def post(self, request):` instead of `def bot(request)`.

`self` is a required argument. Ref: [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)

Use `post` because `bot` is not a valid HTTP method. class `View` expects a valid HTTP method name to be used as the method name.
Ref 1: [Handling forms with Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views)
Ref 2: [_allowed_methods](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L104)